# Plane $x-2y-z=4$ which parametric line is normal?

Tags: calculus, contest-math, plane-geometry

Plane $x-2y-z=4$ which parametric line is normal?
A) $x=1$, $y=-2t$, $z=-t$
B) $x=2t$, $y=5-4t$, $z=-7-2t$
C) $x=-t$, $y=5+2t$, $z=-7-t$
D) $x=\cos(t)$, $y=-2\sin(t)$, $z=-2\sin(t)\cos(t)$
E) NONE

Its forbidden to use options to find answer,options are only for that we check if we find answer correct

And this is my first post here forgive me if a made something wrong,and my english is not quite good for math.And I tried so much to solve this but with out a dot ı couldnt please dont scold and help me to solve this

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I found the normal its N=(1,-2,-1), I tried to found a dot ı couldnt,I tried to dot product with plane’s equation didnt work,I tried to found a line in plane couldnt,ı tried sina=1,Convert the plane’s equation to parametric didnt work and I couldnt find anything on internet I search for a similar question couldnt find any,tried to search a formula for this couldnt find any.

Answer (score 1):

If you found that $N=(1,-2,-1)$ is a normal vector, then a normal line is given by multiples of this vector, hence $r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(t,-2t,-t)$. Now if you translate the line in the space you still get an orthogonal line to the plane. What matters are the coefficients of $t$, which must be proportional to $(1,-2,-1)$. So the line $s(t) = 2r(t) = (2t,-4t,-2t)$ will be orthogonal to your plane, and by translating it you obtain that all lines of the form $(2t+a,-4t+b,-2t+c)$ are orthogonal. Choose $a=0,b=5,c=-7$.

Comment: I tried this too but its not a option so the answer was E)none?

Comment: I am sorry, I read $x=t$ in option A, I edit my answer.

Comment: Thx so much but a last question when ı wrote this answer is it looks like i used the options?

Comment: Well you have to use an option at some point. As I wrote there are infinitely many choices, but the problem gives only one. So you need to recognize option B is fine.

Comment: So we couldnt find a dot from plane equation right?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: I mean,Can’t we find a dot’s coordinate on the plane with using plane’s equation?

Comment: And if ı put a,b,c to x,y,z on the plane equation it makes 3=4?

Comment: You can take any point in the space, the normal direction you have found, and trace a line with that direction. In general the point which you start with and the point of intersection between the line and the plane do not need to coincide.